# push recursive submodules - upload-pack: not our ref

Tags: git

When trying to push to production this error is thrown

```
remote: Cloning into '/var/www/domain.com/php/repo/api/log'...
remote: fatal: remote error: upload-pack: not our ref fdbef7944df6b5e83715f8679395a852dc5faf5e
remote: Fetched in submodule path 'php/repo/api/log', but it did not contain fdbef7944df6b5e83715f8679395a852dc5faf5e. Direct fetching of that commit failed.
```

Paths to the repos

```
php/repo/api
php/repo/api/log <-- the repo nested inside another repo
```

hooks/post-receive

```
#/bin/sh
cd /var/www/domain.com
git --work-tree=. --git-dir=/var/git_repos/domain.com.git checkout master -f
git --work-tree=. --git-dir=/var/git_repos/domain.com.git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've instructed another Git—the one on your server—to clone a submodule, which it did.  Where it got the submodule is not something *I* can answer, but presumably, it used your `.gitmodules` file to get a URL for some third server, and ran `git clone` using that URL to create the submodule repository on your server.

Having created or updated that submodule on the server, you then had the server's submodule's Git try to check out a specific commit, namely the one whose hash ID is `fdbef7944df6b5e83715f8679395a852dc5faf5e`.  Your server's submodule repository did not have `fdbef7944df6b5e83715f8679395a852dc5faf5e` in it.  This is probably because the third server, from which the submodule on the server is cloned, also does not have it.

This is very hard to follow, but we can make it easier to follow if we give *each Git repository a name*.  There are at least 5 repositories in all:

- You have a superproject repository; we'll call him Fred.
- Your superproject has a submodule.  We'll call her Wilma.
- Your server has a Git repository that also acts as a superproject.  We'll call him Barney, though he's mainly really a clone of Fred (or vice versa).
- Your server has a Git repository that acts as a submodule.  We'll call this one Betty.
- Betty is herself a clone, of course (because all Git repositories are clones).  Who is she a clone of?  That's what I don't know (but you can find out / control through your `.gitmodules` file), but we'll call her [Ann Margrock](https://flintstones.fandom.com/wiki/Ann-Margrock).

What's going on here is that you made a new commit in Fred.  This new commit calls for Wilma or Betty, as the submodule, to use commit `fdbef7944df6b5e83715f8679395a852dc5faf5e`.  Presumably, you did actually make commit `fdbef7944df6b5e83715f8679395a852dc5faf5e` in Wilma.

You then had your Git push from Fred to Barney.  Barney now has a commit in him that *also* calls for commit `fdbef7944df6b5e83715f8679395a852dc5faf5e` from his submodule.  But his submodule is Betty.

To *get* `fdbef7944df6b5e83715f8679395a852dc5faf5e`, Betty can make a phone call to Ann Margrock.  But if Ann doesn't have `fdbef7944df6b5e83715f8679395a852dc5faf5e` either, Betty won't *get* `fdbef7944df6b5e83715f8679395a852dc5faf5e`.  When Barney commands Betty to check out `fdbef7944df6b5e83715f8679395a852dc5faf5e`, she will complain, saying that she can't do that.

The solution is to give commit `fdbef7944df6b5e83715f8679395a852dc5faf5e`, not to Barney, nor to Betty, but rather to *Ann*, because Betty is calling Ann to get it.  So figure out who represents Ann here and make sure that Wilma sends `fdbef7944df6b5e83715f8679395a852dc5faf5e` to Ann.