# Get latest commit from a branch other than master branch to submodule

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-submodules

I have 2 ADO repositories - Repo1 & Repo2

Repo1 is set as a submodule in Repo2

```
[submodule "Repo1"]
    path = Repo1
    url = https://xyz.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/abc/_git/Repo1
```

Let's say I made a change in Repo1 and a new commit is added to 'test' branch (**NOT** 'master' branch).

I need to get that commit in the submodule in Repo2.

When I tried:

```
git clone <url-of-Repo2>
cd Repo1
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

I only see latest commit from 'master' branch not 'test' branch. How can I get latest commit from 'test' branch to submodule?

Comment: Superprojects tell submodules to check out commits by raw hash IDs. *Branch names* do not enter this picture. See aslo my recent reply to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65191385/1256452). It's not exactly the same, but should help you think about the problem.

Comment: Thank you! I understand that superprojects tell submodules to check out commits by raw hash IDs. My question is how to get most recent commit raw hash ID from a test branch in the submodule?

Comment: Ah, then it's as [jthill said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65191551/1256452): enter the submodule and check out / switch to the desired commit (`git -C path/to/submodule checkout ...`), then add the submodule back in the superproject (to get the right commit hash ID into GIt's index) using `git add path/to/submodule` and then make a new commit in the superproject. The `git commit -am ...` in his answer is just add-and-commit combined into one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do your submodule updates in the repos using the submodules, not in the submodules themselves.

```
git -C Repo1 checkout test
```

and if you want to add/commit it, do that,

```
git commit -am "Update Repo1 to its 'test' branch tip"
```

Comment: Thank you! With the approach you suggested, I made the update within the submodule in Repo2 and added a new commit. That means Repo2 with submodule will have this commit and Repo1 will not have this commit correct?

Comment: A submodule is just an ordinary repository that has commits some other history wants checked out somewhere specific. The `git submodule` command helps you wrangle such repos, but it doesn't do anything mysterious. `git add` of a repo adds that repo's `HEAD` commit id. When you commit that, it puts that commit id in the snapshot, just as it puts blob id's in the snapshot, the only difference is, Git expects the actual content for blobs to be packed up with the snapshots. For commit ids, it doesn't, instead of Git putting the blob content there you get to find that commit and check it out there.